# CFG for A = { w | w has odd length where first, middle and last symbols are equal }, w from {0,1}* (epsilon is in the language)

Tags: context-free-grammar

A = { w | w has odd length where first, middle and last symbols are equal }, w from {0,1}* (epsilon is in the language)

ε, 011101010, 10101, 1 are in the language.

Let 'e' is an epsilon.

S -> 0X0X0 | 1X1X1 | e

Bad, I don't know length of both X's. Because of that my middle symbol would not be in the middle anymore....

S -> X0X | X1X | e

X -> 10X | 01X | 1 | 0

Bad, w can starts with 0 and ends with 1 and length can be even

I don't have an idea....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight forward would be the following grammar

```
S -> 0X0 | 1Y1 | 0 | 1 | e
X -> 0X0 | 0X1 | 1X0 | 1X1 | 0
Y -> 0Y0 | 0Y1 | 1Y0 | 1Y1 | 1
```

Ie the first character of the word determines whether you go into `X` or `Y`. An `X` always has an odd number of arbitrary characters, with the middle character being a `0`. An `Y` is more or less the same, just that the middle character is `1`.

I don't say it's the minimal grammar, but it should do the trick ...

Comment: Thank you @derpirscher, I'm just started thinking about union. One more thing, since 1 and 0 are in the language I can add them in S, right?

Comment: Yes, if `0` or `1` are also in the language, just add them to `S`

Comment: I think that the answer before edit was more correct because first, middle and last symbols must be the same. In edited answer it could happened that starts with 0 and ends with 1.

Comment: @avukalov Thanks. Yeah, i realized that myself, so I reverted the edit ...

Answer (score -1):

as the CFG should be of odd Length

{0,1,111,000,010,101,00000,11111,10101,01010,01000,10111,11101,00010,.....}

S -> 0X0 | 1Y1 | 0 | 1

X -> 0X0 | 0X1 | 1X0 | 1X1 | 0

Y -> 0Y0 | 0Y1 | 1Y0 | 1Y1 | 1

Comment: OP mentions explicitly, that "*epsilon is in the language*". Your grammar does not allow epsilon. For the rest, it's just a plain copy of my answer above ...